# Fetch Text from webpage using java

Tags: java, android, fetch

I am trying to fetch Text from a webpage using java i tried this code but it is returning empty string. i want do this without any library. So help me Please i am new in java.

**Here is code**

```
public String checkUpdate(){

        String responseText;

        int responseCode;

        try{

            String urlString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/farhanaliofficial/Lite/main/version.txt";

            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.setRequestProperty("accept","*/*");

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());

            

//          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

//          String line;

//

//          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

//              responseBuilder.append(line);

//          }

//          reader.close();

//          responseText = responseBuilder.toString();

            if(responseCode == 200){

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                responseBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());

            }

            responseText = responseBuilder.toString();

            }else{

                responseText = responseCode+"";

            }

        }

        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            responseText = e.toString();

        }

        return responseText;

    }
```

I tried **BufferedReader** but the result is same everytime.

I tried many codes but nothing Works for me. please solve this issue or suggest me other method.

Comment: Debug this. Take a look at what `responseCode` is.

Comment: responseCode is also empty

Comment: Your code works for me. Output is 0.02

Comment: @FarhanAli responseCode cannot be empty, it's an `int`.

Comment: I don't no why it is mot working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It works.

```
Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/farhanaliofficial/Lite/main/version.txt").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String publicIP = "";
        if (s != null) {
            publicIP = s.next();
        }
        System.out.println("version is " + publicIP);
```

Output is version is 0.02

Comment: Why should OP try it?

Comment: I think if it works for OP, then it is worth trying.

Comment: @FarhanAli does it work for you?

Comment: No, not working for me. But my codes work for @Jens not for me

Comment: @sajidjuneja your code works in terminal program but not in Android project